# Spread ends up with individual character

Tags: javascript

I have the following object.

```
const data = {
    mainId: 'AABB',
    alternateId: 'AADD',
    content: {
        all_content: [
            {
                id: 'AAAA'
            },
            {
                id: 'AABB'
            },
            {
                id: 'AACC'
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

When I perform the following operation on it:

```
let result = data.content.all_content
    .filter(d => d.id !== data.mainId)
    .map(d => d.id)
```

I end up with `['AAAA', 'AACC']`

This is correct.

I want to carry on mapping and add to this array as follows:

```
let result = data.content.all_content
    .filter(d => d.id !== data.mainId)
    .map(d => d.id)
    .map(d => [data.alternateId, ...d])
```

I expected it to results as:

```
['AAAA', 'AACC', 'AADD'] // order doesn't matter
```

But instead I end up with:

```
[
    ['AADD', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
    ['AADD', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C']
]
```

Why? How could I fix this?

Comment: Because you spread the string

Comment: in second `map()`, `d` is not an object nor an array, it's a single value

Comment: `map` doesn't add anything to arrays, it maps.  But you could map and spread, so just do -> `let result = [data.alternateId, ...data.content.all_content.filter(d => ......).map(...)];`